# salt water conductivity

Tags: electrical-resistance, physical-chemistry, conductors, ions

my book says the following on conductivity in water with ions. I am confused about why electrons from the zinc (anode) repel positive ions. Because zinc becomes negative, shouldn't it attract it?

> "At the same time this action is going on the electrons from the zinc,
>   which are released near the surface of it repel the positive charges
>   (ions) which are already in the solution, so that those that are near
>   the copper electrode are attracted to it and cling to the surface of
>   it thus charging it positively. As the electrons, which form the
>   current, reach the copper plate through the external circuit they
>   neutralize the positive charges that are deposited on it."

--How to Understand Electricity by A. Frederick Collins

Comment: Looks like seriously garbled writing.  But since you didn't include the sentence defining "...this action ..." , it's hard to clarify.  My guess is the author is mixing comments about the electron flow in the wiring with comments about ion flow in the solution.

Comment: yes, that is correct.